# S3 object lock behaviour after unlocked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

From the [Object Lock docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lock.html):

> When you lock an object version, Amazon S3 stores the lock information in the metadata for that object version. Placing a retention period or legal hold on an object protects only the version specified in the request. It doesn't prevent new versions of the object from being created. If you put an object into a bucket that has the same key name as an existing, protected object, Amazon S3 creates a new version of that object, stores it in the bucket as requested, and reports the request as completed successfully. The existing, protected version of the object remains locked according to its retention configuration.

Assuming my bucket does not apply retention period by default, and I have a newly created S3 object with a legal hold. I overwrite it with another file twice. Will only the original version be protected, and all subsequent uploads be squashed into one version?

After I disable the legal hold,

1. Are my versions still maintained?
2. Will all further uploads overwrite the latest version?
3. If I delete the object, are all versions deleted? Or only the latest version?

Comment: You can test this yourself by creating a bucket with a test object. Let us know what you find!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing,

1. Since versioning is already on, versions are still maintained
2. Subsequent uploads will still have their own versions
3. Only the latest version, unless you specify a version id